# prevent loading other user data ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

We have an application with

- Front-End - React
- Backend - ASP.NET Web API

We have a third party that handles login authentication and authorization roles are handled by back-end application. We also have JWT token exchanged between front-end and back-end. I need to know how to prevent a user who has been authenticated and authorized to view other user details. For example lets say there is a GET call

- GET /Document/{documentid}

The user is able to change the documentid and view other user document. When I looked at the forums, there was a solution where we compare the userid associated to the documentid and userid set while login and compare to make sure both matches and if it matches then the request is a good one. If that's the solution we can have, I can have a middleware to do it but then how can I handle for each table for example there is applicationid, documentid, relationid etc and we dont have userid added to each table. so whats the best way to handle the issue?

Comment: Well the solution is as you said to only allow users to see what they have access to.  Example if document contains userID then check it against the logged in user and then allow access.  Regarding how you do it for each table is is I believe is opinion based and there are many solutions so find what works best for you.

Comment: Yes any suggestions on how to implement on different table because I cannot add userid column at this time. For each api call I need to check if logged in userid is same as userid associates to document, application and so on. That’s what I’m thinking

Comment: So assuming you have Userid in each of the tables you need to check you could Implement an interface enforcing userid is present that way you can just the userid against any table.